# How would you implement a Grid in a functional language?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, ocaml, lazy-evaluation, self-reference

I am interrested in different ways of implementing a constant grid in a functional language. A perfect solution should provide traversal in pesimistic constant time per step and not use imperative constructs (laziness is ok). Solutions not quite fulfilling those requirements are still welcome.

My proposal is based on four-way linked nodes like so

[image: References of a node]

A fundamental operation would be to construct a grid of given size. It seems that this operation will determine the type, i.e. which directions will be lazy (obviously this data structure cannot be achieved without laziness). So I propose (in OCaml)

```
type 'a grid =
  | GNil
  | GNode of 'a * 'a grid Lazy.t * 'a grid Lazy.t * 'a grid * 'a grid
```

With references ordered: left, up, right, down. Left and up are suspended. I then build the grid diagonal-wise

[image: Construction process]

Here is a `make_grid` function that constructs a grid of given size with the coordinate tuples as node values. Please note that `gl`, `gu`, `gr`, `gd` functions allow walking on a grid in all directions and if given `GNil`, will return `GNil`.

```
let make_grid w h =
  let lgnil = Lazy.from_val GNil in
  let rec build_ur x y ls dls = match ls with
    | l :: ((u :: _) as ls') ->
      if x = w && y = h then
        GNode ((x, y), l, u, GNil, GNil)
      else if x < w && 1 < y then
        let rec n = lazy (
          let ur = build_ur (x + 1) (y - 1) ls' (n :: dls) in
          let r = gd ur in
          let d = gl (gd r)
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, r, d)
        )
        in force n
      else if x = w then 
        let rec n = lazy (
          let d = build_dl x (y + 1) (n :: dls) [lgnil]
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, GNil, d)
        )
        in force n
      else
        let rec n = lazy (
          let r = build_dl (x + 1) y (lgnil :: n :: dls) [lgnil] in
          let d = gl (gd r)
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, r, d)
        )
        in force n
    | _ -> failwith "make_grid: Internal error"
  and build_dl x y us urs = match us with
    | u :: ((l :: _) as us') ->
      if x = w && y = h then
        GNode ((x, y), l, u, GNil, GNil)
      else if 1 < x && y < h then
        let rec n = lazy (
          let dl = build_dl (x - 1) (y + 1) us' (n :: urs) in
          let d = gr dl in
          let r = gu (gr d)
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, r, d)
        )
        in force n
      else if y = h then
        let rec n = lazy (
          let r = build_ur (x + 1) y (n :: urs) [lgnil]
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, r, GNil)
        )
        in force n
      else (* x = 1 *)
        let rec n = lazy (
          let d = build_ur x (y + 1) (lgnil :: n :: urs) [lgnil] in
          let r = gu (gr d)
          in GNode ((x, y), l, u, r, d)
        )
        in force n
    | _ -> failwith "make_grid: Internal error"
  in build_ur 1 1 [lgnil; lgnil] [lgnil]
```

It looks pretty complicated as it has to separately handle case when we're going up and when we're going down – `build_ur` and `build_dl` auxiliary functions respectively. The `build_ur` function is of type

```
build_ur :
  int -> int ->
  (int * int) grid Lazy.t list -> 
  (int * int) grid Lazy.t list -> (int * int) grid
```

It construct a node, given the current position `x` and `y`, the list of suspended elements of **previous** diagonal `ls`, the list of suspended previous elements of **current** diagonal `urs`. The name `ls` comes from the fact that the first element on `ls` is the left neighbour of current node. The `urs` list is needed for construction of the next diagonal.

The `build_urs` function proceeds with building the next node on the up-right diagonal, passing the current node in a suspension. The *left* and *up* neighbour are taken from `ls` and the *right* and *down* neighbours can be accessed through the next node on the diagonal.

Note that I put a bunch of `GNil`s on the `urs` and `ls` lists. This is made to always ensure that `build_ur` and `build_dl` can consume at least two elements from those lists.

[image: A step of <code>build_ur</code>]

The `build_dl` function works analogously.

This implementation seems overly complicated for such a simple data structure. In fact I'm suprised it works cause I was driven by faith when writing it and am unable to comprehend completely why it works. Therefore I would like to know a simpler solution.

I was considering building the grid row-wise. This approach has less border cases but I can't eliminate the need of building subsequent rows in different directions. It's because when I go to the end with a row and would like to start building another from the beginning, I would have to somehow know the *down* node of the first node in current row, which I seemingly can't know until I return from the current function call. And if I can't eliminate bi-directionality, I would need two inner node constructiors: one with suspended *left* and *top* and the other with suspended *right* and *top*.

[image: The continuation problem]

Also, here is a gist of this implementation along with omitted functions: https://gist.github.com/mkacz91/0e63aaa2a67f8e67e56f

Comment: This question is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not asking to improve my implementation but ask If someone has an approach that is conceptually different.

Comment: This is pretty impressive, but if you find it difficult to get the results you want you could consider just using references. OCaml is a mixed paradigm language (so they tell me), so you can program in the style of C or Java if you like.

Comment: I'm aware that in imperative paradigm this is a no issue. But I want to tackle it in a functional way out of pure curiosity. Besides this will be part of my project assignment in functional programming, so I'd rather resort to imperative tools as little as possible.

Comment: I think I probably would suggest an `'a Lazy.t IntPairMap.t`. Maybe that's too obvious :)

Comment: Why remove OCaml from the title and from the tags? Also, imposing a purely functional approach to solving a grid problem is like building a model ship in a bottle. It can be an interesting exercise, but it's a terrible way of building miniature ships.

Comment: I removed reference to OCaml because one person posted a solution in Haskell and I realized I could cope with any language. And about the inefficiency argument: You're right and this is indeed an excercise. Besides, what's the whole point in functional programming if we resort to imperative constructs every time we encounter a problem. I also realize I'm kind of deprecating your hash table proposal by imposing functional approach. Sorry for that. I should have been more clear from the beginning.

Comment: why you claimed `obviously this data structure cannot be achieved without laziness`

Comment: In a purely functional language you can't change the value of a pointer once it's created. This means you can't "dynamically" create cyclic structures (OCaml actually allows self reference if the whole structure is known at compile time, i.e., is "static"). Laziness with memoization is a sneaky way to introduce impure mechanics but it's restricted enough to sometimes be considered pure. By saying "it cannot be achieved without laziness" I meant it's the only way to achieve it if we don't want to use impure pointer modification.

Answer (score 2):

The datastructure you are looking for if you want a functional solution is a [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)). I've written the rest of the code in Haskell because I find it more to my taste but it's easily ported to OCaml. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2664786ad59cec74c683) without the interleaved comments.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Grid where

import Data.Maybe
```

We can start by understanding the datastructure for just lists: you can think of a zipper as a pointer deep inside a list. You have wathever is on the left of the element you point at, then the element you point at and finally whatever is on the right.

```hs
type ListZipper a = ([a], a, [a])
```

Given a list and an integer `n`, you can focus on the element which is at position `n`. Of course, if `n` is greater than the lenght of the list, then you just fail. One important thing to notice is that the left part of the list is stored *backwards*: moving the focus to the left will therefore be possible in constant time. As will moving to the right.

```hs
focusListAt :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
focusListAt = go []
  where
    go _   _ []        = Nothing
    go acc 0 (hd : tl) = Just (acc, hd, tl)
    go acc n (hd : tl) = go (hd : acc) (n - 1) tl
```

Let's move on to Grids now. A `Grid` will just be a list of rows (lists).

```hs
newtype Grid a = Grid { unGrid :: [[a]] }
```

A zipper for a `Grid` is now given by a grid representing everything `above` the current focus, another representing everything `below` it, and a list zipper (advanced level: notice that this looks a bit like nested list zippers & could be reformulated in more generic terms).

```hs
data GridZipper a =
  GridZipper { above :: Grid a
             , below :: Grid a
             , left  :: [a]
             , right :: [a]
             , focus :: a }
```

By focusing on the right row first, and then the right element we may focus a `Grid` at some coordinates `x` and `y`.

```hs
focusGridAt :: Int -> Int -> Grid a -> Maybe (GridZipper a)
focusGridAt x y g = do
  (before, line , after) <- focusListAt x $ unGrid g
  (left  , focus, right) <- focusListAt y line
  let above = Grid before
  let below = Grid after
  return GridZipper{..}
```

Once we have a zipper, we can move around easily. The code for going either left or right is not suprisingly rather similar:

```hs
goLeft :: GridZipper a -> Maybe (GridZipper a)
goLeft g@GridZipper{..} =
  case left of
    []      -> Nothing
    (hd:tl) -> Just $ g { focus = hd, left = tl, right = focus : right }

goRight :: GridZipper a -> Maybe (GridZipper a)
goRight g@GridZipper{..} =
  case right of
    []      -> Nothing
    (hd:tl) -> Just $ g { focus = hd, left = focus : left, right = tl }
```

When going up or down, we have to be a bit careful because we need to focus on the spot right above (or below) the one we left in the new row. We also have to reassemble the previous row we were focused onto into a good old list (by appending the reversed `left` to `focus : right`).

```hs
goUp :: GridZipper a -> Maybe (GridZipper a)
goUp GridZipper{..} = do
  let (line : above')     = unGrid above
  let below'              = (reverse left ++ focus : right) : unGrid below
  (left', focus', right') <- focusListAt (length left) line
  return $ GridZipper { above = Grid above'
                      , below = Grid below'
                      , left  = left'
                      , right = right'
                      , focus = focus' }

goDown :: GridZipper a -> Maybe (GridZipper a)
goDown GridZipper{..} = do
  let (line : below')     = unGrid below
  let above'              = (reverse left ++ focus : right) : unGrid above
  (left', focus', right') <- focusListAt (length left) line
  return $ GridZipper { above = Grid above'
                      , below = Grid below'
                      , left  = left'
                      , right = right'
                      , focus = focus' }
```

Finally, I've also added a couple of helper functions to generate grids (with every cell containing a pair of its coordinates) and instances to be able to display grids and zippers in a terminal.

```hs
mkGrid :: Int -> Int -> Grid (Int, Int)
mkGrid m n = Grid $ [ zip (repeat i) [0..n-1] | i <- [0..m-1] ]

instance Show a => Show (Grid a) where
  show = concatMap (('\n' :) . concatMap show) . unGrid

instance Show a => Show (GridZipper a) where
  show GridZipper{..} =
    concat [ show above, "\n"
           , concatMap show (reverse left)
           , "\x1B[33m[\x1B[0m",  show focus, "\x1B[33m]\x1B[0m"
           , concatMap show right
           , show below ]
```

`main` creates a small grid of size 5*10, focuses on the element at coordinates (2,3) and moves around a bit.

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let grid1 = mkGrid 5 10
  print grid1
  let grid2 = fromJust $ focusGridAt 2 3 grid1
  print grid2
  print $ goLeft =<< goLeft =<< goDown =<< goDown grid2
```

Comment: This optimizes the left and right operations, but has issues with the up and down. One way to resolve this is to have the structure become a `'a Zipper.t Zipper.t`, with the addition of the index to `'a` you can reduce the `List.length` operations that would slow things down.

Comment: Another alternative, would be to use an inductive graph -- http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf

Comment: This is nice because it's purely functional. But another flaw is that if I have multiple zippers traversing the grid long enough, I will end up with multiple copies of the grid. Of course the values will not be copied, but the _skeleton_, i.e. constructors, will be duplicated.

Comment: they will also be cleaned up by the garbage collector pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for implementing infinite grids consists in using a hash table indexed by the coordinate pairs.

The following is a sample implementation that doesn't check for integer overflow:

```
type 'a cell = {
  x: int; (* position on the horizontal axis *)
  y: int; (* position on the vertical axis *)
  value: 'a;
}

type 'a grid = {
  cells: (int * int, 'a cell) Hashtbl.t;
  init_cell: int -> int -> 'a;
}

let create_grid init_cell = {
  cells = Hashtbl.create 10;
  init_cell;
}

let hashtbl_get tbl k =
  try Some (Hashtbl.find tbl k)
  with Not_found -> None

(* Check if we have a cell at the given relative position *)
let peek grid cell x_offset y_offset =
  hashtbl_get grid.cells (cell.x + x_offset, cell.y + y_offset)

(* Get the cell at the given relative position *)
let get grid cell x_offset y_offset =
  let x = cell.x + x_offset in
  let y = cell.y + y_offset in
  let k = (x, y) in
  match hashtbl_get grid.cells k with
  | Some c -> c
  | None ->
      let new_cell = {
        x; y;
        value = grid.init_cell x y
      } in
      Hashtbl.add grid.cells k new_cell;
      new_cell

let left grid cell = get grid cell (-1) 0
let right grid cell = get grid cell 1 0
let down grid cell = get grid cell 0 (-1)
(* etc. *)
```